# How can I make the GMail app open to the accounts page when using multiple accounts

Tags: settings, gmail

When I open the Gmail application, it opens the last inbox I looked at. Is there a way to make it always open to the "Accounts" page instead?

*I have an HTC incredible 2 if that matters.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not find a way to do this every time the app starts. I did discover that if multiple accounts have new messages at the same time, the app starts on the "Accounts" page.

It seems when you start the app it opens the account with new messages automatically, and only opens the "Accounts" list if multiple accounts contain new messages.